# Commutativity of comodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra, coalgebras

If C is a cocommutative R-coalgebra, R is some commutative semi-simple artinian ring and A and B are C-bicomodules, then is $A\otimes_R B \cong B \otimes_R A$ as $R-modules$.  However, this also true as $C$-bicomdodules.

*(If not, would assuming C is also commutative have any result?)*

Comment: HAha, ya.. i was trying to recruit some peopel to this question, by mosre standard tage... :0 (<- a little confession)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is how would such an isomorphism look like. Say we just take $f\colon a\otimes b \mapsto b\otimes a$ and ask whether this is a $C$-bicomodule homomorphism. Then we would ne to prove that for example $$ \sum_{(b)}b_{(0)}\otimes a \otimes b_{(1)} = \sum_{(a)}b\otimes a_{(0)}\otimes a_{(1)}.$$
But it is very easy to construct counterexamples to this in a very general way:

Let $\alpha,\beta\in C$ be two distinct group-like elements. Then for any $R$-modules $A$ and $B$ the comultiplications $a\mapsto a\otimes \alpha$ and $b\mapsto b\otimes \beta$ are comodule structures. But:
$$b\otimes a \otimes \beta \neq b\otimes a \otimes \alpha.$$